# Will methods get run on Spring Neo4j `@NodeEntity` objects created by the empty constructor?

Tags: spring, neo4j

I have read that Neo4j requires `@NodeEntity`s to be declared with an empty constructor available.

I don't have any idea why this is required.

However, it means that if an object is created using that version of the constructor, then surely its `@Property` fields will be null.

This seems to imply that all methods on the `NodeEntity` class need to deal with this possibility, which is painful.

The possibility of those fields being null can be eliminated with the constructor version that the application code uses.

So the question is: is there any risk that these methods will be called on an object created with that empty constructor?

(The application never uses that constructor explicitly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found my own answer: it is yes.

The empty constructor is (or appears to be) used when constructing objects that are the result of a query.

And any `@Property` can be null if the query didn't load it.